# I want to add text on the link in D3.js tree graph

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, tree, label

I want to make a decision tree in D3.js and to add text on the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body><script src="../d3-master/d3.min.js"></script>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../D3css/D3css.css"></head>

<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  rect_width = 90,
  rect_height = 20;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height * 2, width / 2]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("../data/ID3.json", function(error, root) {

    var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("calss", "link")
        .attr("fill", "none");

    link.append("path")
        .attr("d", diagonal)
        .attr("stroke", "lightsteelblue");

    link.append("text")
        .data(nodes)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
        .attr("y", -85)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .text(function(d) { return d.rule; });

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    node.append("rect")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-42,-8)")
        .attr("width", rect_width)
        .attr("height", rect_height)
      .style("fill", "lightsteelblue");

    node.append("text")
       .attr("dy", ".31em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x / 128 + "," + d.y / 128 + ")"; })
       .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  });

</script>
```

There is no text on the link at the bottom right.
I think to was due to use 'nodes' data.
so, I tried in to use 'root' data.
but, I don't come out of nothing if I use 'root' data.

I think that this part is problem.

link.append("text")
    .data(nodes)

How should I revise??

my data.

```
{ "name" : "0", "rule" : "null",
  "children" : [{ "name" : "2", "rule" : "sunny",
                  "children" : [{ "name" : "no(3/100%)", "rule" : "high" },
                                { "name" : "yes(2/100%)", "rule" : "normal" }]},
                { "name" : "yes(4/100%)", "rule" : "overcast" },
                { "name" : "3", "rule" : "rainy",
                  "children" : [{ "name" : "no(2/100%)", "rule" : "TRUE" },
                                { "name" : "yes(3/100%)", "rule" : "FALSE" }]}]}
```

Comment: For d3 v4, this answer saved me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600142/d3-js-tree-with-numbering-on-nodes

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For links, one can't access `d.x`, `d.y`, `d.rule`, or similar fields, since link is not associated with a single data point, but it has its source and target. This means the data should be accessed like this: `d.source.x`, `d.target.y`, and so on.

The key code segment should look like this:

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "link");

link.append("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "#ff8888")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1.5px")
    .attr("d", diagonal);

link.append("text")
    .attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
    .attr("fill", "Black")
    .style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" +
            ((d.source.y + d.target.y)/2) + "," + 
            ((d.source.x + d.target.x)/2) + ")";
    })   
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
        console.log(d.target.rule);
         return d.target.rule;
    });
```

Here is working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B8YDM/)

[image]

Of course, you can change text color, position, etc. to suit your needs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, this code doesn't support d3 V4, any way to support V4?