# Add text on mouseover to links, add filtering, and zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add text that appears next to each edge/link on mouseover, to the below d3 graph. I would also like to add a filtering capability that allows a user to click on a node, and only see its direct connections. Finally I would like to add a zoom functionality.

I have tried adding to the links directly by .append("text") (see below) and trying other things from various other posts (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360847/i-want-to-add-text-on-the-link-in-d3-js-tree-graph) for example), but am not having any success. (Whenever I add an attribute to the link to hold the next, the links themselves disappear). Does anyone know how I can proceed here?

For the filtering and zooming I don't have a clue how to start, so any tips here would also be great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body> 
<style>
.link {
stroke: #666;
opacity: 0.6;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node circle {
stroke: #fff;
opacity: 0.6;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
text {
font: 7px serif;
opacity: 0.6;
pointer-events: none;
}
</style>

<script src=http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js></script>

<script> 
 var links = [ { "source" : "A", "target" : "B" }, { "source" : "A", "target" : "C" }, { "source" : "A", "target" : "D" }, { "source" : "A", "target" : "J" }, { "source" : "B", "target" : "E" }, { "source" : "B", "target" : "F" }, { "source" : "C", "target" : "G" }, { "source" : "C", "target" : "H" }, { "source" : "D", "target" : "I" } ] ; 
 var nodes = {}

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
link.source = nodes[link.source] ||
(nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
link.target = nodes[link.target] ||
(nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
link.value = +link.value;
});

var width = 400
height = 250;

var force = d3.layout.force()
.nodes(d3.values(nodes))
.links(links)
.size([width, height])
.linkDistance(50)
.charge(-500)
.on("tick", tick)
.start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
.data(force.links())
.enter().append("line")
.attr("class", "link");

link.append("text")
  .attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
.attr("fill", "Black")
.style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" +
        ((d.source.y + d.target.y)/2) + "," + 
        ((d.source.x + d.target.x)/2) + ")";
})   
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(d) {
    console.log(d.target.rule);
     return d.target.rule;
});

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(force.nodes())
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "node")
.on("mouseover", mouseover)
.on("mouseout", mouseout)
.on("click", click)
.on("dblclick", dblclick)
.call(force.drag);

node.append("circle")
.attr("r", 8)
.style("fill", "#3182bd");

node.append("text")
.attr("x", 12)
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.style("fill", "#3182bd")
.text(function(d) { return d.name; });

function tick() {
link
.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
.attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
.attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
.attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y +     ")"; });
}

function mouseover() {
d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
.duration(750)
.attr("r", 16);
}

function mouseout() {
d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
.duration(750)
.attr("r", 8);
}
// action to take on mouse click
function click() {
d3.select(this).select("text").transition()
.duration(750)
.attr("x", 22)
.style("stroke-width", ".5px")
.style("opacity", 1)
.style("fill", "#E34A33")
.style("font", "17.5px serif");
d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
.duration(750)
.style("fill", "#E34A33")
.attr("r", 16)
}

// action to take on mouse double click
function dblclick() {
d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
.duration(750)
.attr("r", 6)
.style("fill", "#E34A33");
d3.select(this).select("text").transition()
.duration(750)
.attr("x", 12)
.style("stroke", "none")
.style("fill", "#E34A33")
.style("stroke", "none")
.style("opacity", 0.6)
.style("font", "7px serif");
}

 </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: You cant append text to the link directly, svg doesnt allow that. So append it to the thing the link is appended to. But i would recommend creating a div and do it like this : http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369. As for the zoom, this is the best example i have used : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708. As for the connected nodes(filtering/neighbours) look at this example : http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/. Go down to 'H' for highlighting.I would recommend researching more before asking as these are easily found. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Didn't have enough room on the comments.

If you didnt want to add a div for you tooltip and just append text I would do it like this :

```
var links = svg.selectAll(".link")
.data(force.links())
.enter();

var link = links.append("line")
.attr("class", "link");

//and for text 

var linkText = links.append('text') //not append to the link directly but the link container
//and so on
```

As I have mentioned, you cant append text to a shape so you have to append it to the element the shape is appended to.