# D3.js Tree with Numbering on Nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

### index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    .node rect {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    .arrow {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
 
 var treeData = {
      "name": "File 1",
       "children": [{
   "name": "File 2",
   "children": [
   {
    "name": "File 3",
    "children": [{
     "name": "File 4",
     "type": "data"
     }]
   },
   {
    "name": "File 5",
    "children": [{
     "name": "File 6",
     "type": "data",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "File 7"
      },
      {
       "name": "File 8",
       "type": "data"
      }
      ]
     }]
   }
    ],
          }]
    };

    // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 5000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
      nodeEnter.filter(function(d){
        return (!d.data.type || d.data.type !== 'data');
      }).append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr('r', 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });
        
      nodeEnter.filter(function(d){
        return (d.data.type && d.data.type === 'data');
      }).append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr('width', 20)
        .attr('height', 20)
        .attr('y', -10)
        .attr('x', -10)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

  // Add labels for the nodes
      nodeEnter.append('text')
        .attr("dy", "2em")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? 13 : 13;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "start" : "start";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.data.name;
        });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });
  
  svg.append("text")
     .attr("id", "curve-text")
  .append("textPath")
  .attr("xlink:href", "#link")
  .data(treeData, function(d, i){return i;})

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}

</script>
</body>
```

Desired product:

[image]

For each node which has multiple paths to the right of it, the top path should have a `1`, increasing as you're going down, as in the image above. I have already seen https://gist.github.com/mbostock/2565344 and [draw text in d3 arc javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903548/draw-text-in-d3-arc-javascript), but have not been able to add the numbers to the diagram.

I get that you're probably supposed to use `.append('text')`, but I'm not sure how to "append" this to the paths, nor do I know how to appropriately set the properties and the text value in this case. Any answer to this should be scalable - i.e., do not assume that there are only two paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another fun question.  I'd do it like this.

First, change the `linkEnter` to append a `g` and into this `g` append the `path` and `text`.

```
// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('g', 'g')
  .attr("class", "link");

linkEnter.append('path')
  .attr('d', function(d) {
    var o = {
      x: source.x0,
      y: source.y0
    }
    return diagonal(o, o)
  });

linkEnter.append('text')
...
```

Second, To calculate the count, here's a tricky little function based off the parent's children's length and where you are in the iteration of the links:

```
.text(function(d,i) {
  if (d.parent && d.parent.children.length > 1){
    if (!d.parent.index) d.parent.index = 0;
    return ++d.parent.index;
  }
})
```

Finally, for the position, I wouldn't mess around with a `textPath`, it's a bit overkill.  Just calculate the midpoint of the link.

```
.attr('transform', function(d){
  if (d.parent) {
    return 'translate(' + ((d.parent.y + d.y) / 2) + ',' + ((d.parent.x + d.x) / 2) + ')'
  }
})
```

Putting it all together:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    
    .node rect {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    
    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .link path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    
    .link text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .arrow {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var treeData = {
      "name": "File 1",
      "children": [{
        "name": "File 2",
        "children": [{
          "name": "File 3",
          "children": [{
            "name": "File 4",
            "type": "data"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "File 5",
          "children": [{
            "name": "File 6",
            "type": "data",
            "children": [{
              "name": "File 7"
            }, {
              "name": "File 8",
              "type": "data"
            }]
          }]
        }],
      }]
    };

    // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 90,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 90
      },
      width = 5000 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var i = 0,
      duration = 750,
      root;

    // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
    var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

    // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
    root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {
      return d.children;
    });
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;

    // Collapse after the second level
    root.children.forEach(collapse);

    update(root);

    // Collapse the node and all it's children
    function collapse(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children
        d._children.forEach(collapse)
        d.children = null
      }
    }

    function update(source) {

      // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
      var treeData = treemap(root);

      // Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
        links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 180
      });

      // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

      // Update the nodes...
      var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
        .data(nodes, function(d) {
          return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });

      // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        })
        .on('click', click);

      // Add Circle for the nodes
      nodeEnter.filter(function(d) {
          return (!d.data.type || d.data.type !== 'data');
        }).append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr('r', 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

      nodeEnter.filter(function(d) {
          return (d.data.type && d.data.type === 'data');
        }).append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr('width', 20)
        .attr('height', 20)
        .attr('y', -10)
        .attr('x', -10)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

      // Add labels for the nodes
      nodeEnter.append('text')
        .attr("dy", "2em")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? 13 : 13;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "start" : "start";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.data.name;
        });

      // UPDATE
      var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

      // Transition to the proper position for the node
      nodeUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });

      // Update the node attributes and style
      nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
        .attr('r', 10)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        })
        .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


      // Remove any exiting nodes
      var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
        })
        .remove();

      // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
      nodeExit.select('circle')
        .attr('r', 1e-6);

      // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
      nodeExit.select('text')
        .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

      // ****************** links section ***************************

      // Update the links...
      var link = svg.selectAll('g.link')
        .data(links, function(d) {
          return d.id;
        });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('g', 'g')
        .attr("class", "link");
        
      linkEnter.append('path')
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
          }
          return diagonal(o, o)
        });

      linkEnter.append('text')
        .text(function(d,i) {
          if (d.parent && d.parent.children.length > 1){
            if (!d.parent.index) d.parent.index = 0;
            return ++d.parent.index;
          }
        })
        .attr('dy', "-1em");

      // UPDATE
      var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

      // Transition back to the parent element position
      linkUpdate.select('path').transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          return diagonal(d, d.parent)
        });
        
      linkUpdate.select('text').transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('transform', function(d){
          if (d.parent) {
            return 'translate(' + ((d.parent.y + d.y) / 2) + ',' + ((d.parent.x + d.x) / 2) + ')'
          }
        })
        
      // Remove any exiting links
      link.exit().each(function(d){
        d.parent.index = 0;
      })
      
      var linkExit = link.exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(duration);
      
      linkExit.select('path')
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y
          }
          return diagonal(o, o)
        })
        
      linkExit.select('text')
        .style('opacity', 0);
      
      linkExit.remove();

      // Store the old positions for transition.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });

      // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
      function diagonal(s, d) {

        path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

        return path
      }

      // Toggle children on click.
      function click(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
        update(d);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: One last question... how would I remove those numbers if they are no longer in the layout (i.e., I selected, then deselected the corresponding nodes)? Probably something to do with an exit selection? I could probably figure it out, but thought I'd ask if my thinking is correct, at the very least.

Comment: @Clarinetist, wow, I broke all the exit functions and didn't realize.  I am getting old.  Check the *running code* above for updates.  Here's my working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HV7AjOjdrk2j0HD1V5Dj?p=preview) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add text by creating a d3-selection and appending a text element for each link.

```
// Select all text links
var linkText = svg.selectAll('text.link')
    .data(links, function(d) {return d.id});

// Then append the text on the enter selection
var linkEnter = linkText.enter().insert('text','g')
    .attr('class','link')
    .attr('x',function(d){return (d.target.x-d.source.x)/2;})
    .attr('y',function(d){return (d.target.y-d.source.y)/2;})
    .text(function(d){return d['cardinality'];});
```

Note: this only to add the text elements. You'll also need to update the text positions on and update and remove them when those links have been removed. Follow the same structure that you have in the path.link d3-selections that you have for this.

You'll also need a way to calculate 'cardinality' for each link. Which I would assume you can accomplish by looping through the links array and checking if more than one link has the same source, then count up, otherwise give that link a cardinality of 0 or something special.